# When is it necessary to use threading with serial communication in a GUI?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, python-multithreading, pyserial

I am writing a simple GUI using Python 2.7 and the Tkinter module. The GUI needs to interface with two separate devices over serial, and therefore I will use Pyserial.

I will open two serial ports but for the sake of maintaining responsive of the GUI, I have considered using multiple threads to handle any serial back-and-forth between the GUI and the two devices. I would like to know if this is what others would recommend or if there is an alternative approach.

There are a few cases that will occur for my program.

1) The GUI will expect a response or multiple responses from a device only after it has sent the device a command.

2) The GUI will receive a response or multiple responses from a device without prompting it or expecting it.

For the first case, there are two ways in which commands will be to the devices where the GUI will be looking for a response.

1) The user will type in a line and hit send. The device will then respond. I imagine at the speed this would occur, this could get away with not threading if this was all that going on.

2) The GUI will enter a function which will read a text file line by line, each line representing a command to be sent to the device. The function will only send the next line when it receives a confirmation response from the device. Since this function will only end when it reaches the EOF, the user pauses, or the user forces a returns out of the function, the function will take a long time to complete and the GUI would freeze while running it. I feel this should be in its own thread to avoid freezing.

If I feel unprompted responses from the device is going to be a common event during the program or I don't want any kind of GUI unresponsiveness, I can design a function that the thread will take care that all it does is check for responses. I think one thread can handle looking for responses from the multiple devices. The function will also have a check value that will return out of the function where the check value is user-controllable, which should also close the thread.

A second thread will handle running the function which sends commands to the device line by line. The function could be sending some command lines to one device or the other. If I could have both threads open, is it bad to have both checking to see if serial.readline is true?

I would appreciate any input. Thank you.

Comment: You can poll the devices with root.after at, say, 100 millesecond intervals.  In spite of claims that tkinter is not 'thread-safe', you should be able to change displayed values from a sub-thread.  Exact answers depend on what you mean by 'serial port' and the exact handshaking and timing characteristics of the devices.  Experiment, write some code, and when you have a problem, post a minimal example and the error and a specific question.

Comment: I second what Terry has said. use .after to periodically schedule tasks to update the GUI with data from the serial port.